# How to get a 2D output from linear layer in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I would like to project a tensor into a space with an additional dimension.

I tried

```
torch.nn.Linear(
    in_features=num_inputs,
    out_features=(num_inputs, num_additional),
)
```

But this results in an error

A workaround would be to

```
torch.nn.Linear(
    in_features=num_inputs,
    out_features=num_inputs*num_additional,
)
```

and then change the view the output

```
output.view(batch_size, num_inputs, num_additional)
```

But I imagine this workaround will get tricky to read, especially when a projection into more than one additional dimension is desired.

Is there a more direct way to code this operation?

Perhaps the source code for linear can be changed

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/linear.html#Linear

To accept more dimensions for the weight and bias initialization, and `F.linear` seems like it would need to be replaced with a different function.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the workaround you provided is already clear enough. However, if you want to express this as a single operation, you can always write your own module by subclassing `torch.nn.Linear`:

```py
import numpy as np
import torch


class MultiDimLinear(torch.nn.Linear):
    def __init__(self, in_features, out_shape, **kwargs):
        self.out_shape = out_shape
        out_features = np.prod(out_shape)
        super().__init__(in_features, out_features, **kwargs)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = super().forward(x)
        return out.reshape((len(x), *self.out_shape))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tmp = torch.empty((32, 10))
    linear = MultiDimLinear(in_features=10, out_shape=(10, 10))
    out = linear(tmp)
    print(out.shape)  # (32, 10, 10)
```

Comment: Ideally, you would enforce the batch size to remain otherwise you might have unexpected error messages which are hard to track in case of shape mismatch between the input `x` and the parameter `out_shape`. As an alternative, you could return `out.flatten(1)` in your `forward`.

Comment: Good point, I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use torch.einsum

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html

torch.einsum can prevent summation across dimensions in tensor to tensor multiplication operations. This can allow separate multiplication operations to happen in parallel. [ I do not know if this would necessarily result in GPU efficiency; if the operations are still occurring in the same kernel. In fact, it may be slower https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/32591 ]

How this would work is to directly initialize the weight and bias tensors (look at source code for the torch linear layer for that code)

Say that the input (X) has dimensions (a, b), where a is the batch size.

Say that you want to pass this input through a series of classifiers, represented in a single weight tensor (W) with dimensions (c, d, e), where c is the number of classifiers, and e is the number of classes for the classifier

```
import torch
x = torch.arange(2*4).view(2, 4)
w = torch.arange(5*4*6).view(5, 4, 2)
torch.einsum('ab, cbe -> ace', x, w)
```

in the last line, a and b are the dimensions of the input as mentioned above. What might be the tricky part is c, b, and e are the dimensions of the classifiers weight tensor; I didn't use d, I used b instead. That is because the vector multiplication is happening along that dimension for the inputs tensor and the weight tensor. So that's why the left side of the einsum equation is `ab, cbe`. The right side of the einsum equation is simply what dimensions to exclude from summation.

The final dimensions we want is (a, c, e). a is the batch size, c is the number of classifiers, and e is the number of classes for each classifier. We do not want to add those values, so to preserve their separation, the left side of the equation is `ace`.

For those unfamiliar with einsum, this will be harder to read than the word around I created (though I highly recommend learning it, because it gets very easy and intuitive very fast even though it's a bit tricky at first https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkVwUVEHmfI )

However, for paralyzing certain operations (especially on GPU), it seems that einsum is the only way to do it. For example so that in my previous example, I didn't want to use a classification head yet, I just wanted to project to multiple dimensions.

```
import torch
x = torch.arange(2*4).view(2, 4)
w = torch.arange(5*4*6).view(5, 4, 4)
y = torch.einsum('ab, cbe -> ace', x, w)
```

And say I do a few other operations to y, perhaps some non linear operations, activations, etc.

z = f(y)

z will still have the dimensions 2, 5, 4. Batch size two, 5 hidden states per batch, and the dimension of those hidden states are 4.

And then I want to apply a classifier to each separate tensor.

```
w2 = torch.arange(4*2).view(4, 2)
final = torch.einsum('fgh, hj -> fgj', z, w2)
```

Quick refresh, 2 is the batch size, 5 is the number of classifier, and 2 is the number of outputs for each classifier.

The output dimensions, f, g, j (2, 5, 2) will not be summed across, and thus will be preserved in the output.

As cited in the github link, this may be slower than just using regular linear layers. There may be efficiencies in a very large number of parallel operations.